# DB migrate scripts break on references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I've been following online examples of how to create tables the Rails way and I noticed the migration scripts I created containing references don't work out of the box. I thought maybe I did something wrong so I tried just now making a test application/migration against a SQLite3 datasource. I ran the following commands:

```
$ rails g scaffold SchoolClass name
$ rails g scaffold Student name SchoolClass:references
```

And it made my migration scripts (along with everything else).

[Migration script for dependent table with reference to Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x5V3.png)

I ran the SQLite3 migration scripts and it worked fine.

When I tried doing the same steps above against a Postgres datasource, I kept on getting the following:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation does not exist
```

The only way I got past this issue is if I went into the migration script and updated the t.references line and replaced the class name with the actual table name. In the Rails migration guide (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3/migrations.html#special-helpers) it said for the references helper you pass the Model name. In the case with Postgres, this seems not to be the case.

It's a simple enough fix to replace Model names with table names, but I've got a ton of tables to migrate and each table can have a good number of references. Has anyone seen this before, and is there some way to keep on using the scaffold utility to make migrations?

Appreciative of any useful assistance,

- Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `t.references :school_class` instead of `:SchoolClass` And correct scaffold command is `rails g scaffold Student name school_class:references`. See [rails guides on naming conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions)